Tape backup fails with odd MTX errors
First the hardware and software in use. I am using a Qualstar RLS-84000 tape library, plus an expansion, with four IBM LTO-6 drives. The drives are connected to a single x86_64 server via SAS with an LSI SAS2116 based HBA controller. The server is running Rocky 9 with the mpt3sas driver from ElRepo. The backup software in use is Bacula Enterprise v16. Before Rocky 9 was installed the server was running CentOS 7 and never had this particular tape related error.
When the tapes that are set to be used next are loaded and mounted manually Bacula runs with no issue. However when the job needs a different tape mtx causes numerous issues and the backup job doesn't fail but never completes, I have to manually stop it. Here is an example of the errors given from the Bacula job logs.
atoz-sd JobId 467170: 3307 Issuing autochanger "unload Volume 000066L6, Slot 75, Drive 3" command.
atoz-sd JobId 467170: 3995 Bad autochanger "unload Volume 000066L6, Slot 75, Drive 3": ERR=Child exited with code 1
Results=Unloading drive 3 into Storage Element 75...Unloading drive 3 into Storage Element 75...Unloading drive 3 into Storage Element 75...Unloading drive 3 into Storage Element 75...Unloading drive 3 into Storage Element 75...mtx: Request Sense: Long Report=yes
mtx: Request Sense: Valid Residual=no
mtx: Request Sense: Error Code=70 (Current)
mtx: Request Sense: Sense Key=Illegal Request
mtx: Request Sense: FileMark=no
mtx: Request Sense: EOM=no
mtx: Request Sense: ILI=no
mtx: Request Sense: Additional Sense Code = 3B
mtx: Request Sense: Additional Sense Qualifier = 90
mtx: Request Sense: Field in Error = 00
mtx: Request Sense: BPV=no
mtx: Request Sense: Error in CDB=yes
mtx: Request Sense: SKSV=yes
mtx: Request Sense: Field Pointer = 00 04
MOVE MEDIUM from Element Address 1005 to 3075 Failed

Those errors repeat near endlessly and each time it appears represents the tape being rewound, ejected, moved(which fails), reinserted into the drive, then loaded again, all of which causes more wear on an already old tape library, drives, and tapes. I'm currently trying to track down the source of the error. The Bacula support dept has mostly ruled out Bacula itself and the error messages coming from mtx seems to support that. I've checked the dmesg and journald outputs for the system at the times of these errors and nothing related, from mpt3sas, mtx, or bacula, was seen.
Looking for any help on what to do from here that doesn't involve new hardware, unless it's actually bad hardware. I do plan on sending these errors to the mpt3sas developers but I don't know if they can help or not.
